# How to group news based on Tag, Categories , countries using MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table related to news which has various fields such as `Title, Category, Tag, Country, details ...`

I need to show the `related news` based on what news user is reading now.

**related news** could be based on `Tag, Category & Country`

Issue i am facing is that `Tags` i need to search each tag with all the news items for example if news items has 3 tags then it has to search through all news records three times to get the result based on tags which are matched.

I have set up sample table structure on Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d9dd7/1

**Sample Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [TestTable](
    [AutoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Tags] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    Country [nvarchar](50)
)
```

**Example**

Let us say i am reading `This is News One America`

Then related article should  show `This is News five` as it matches the category and two keywords also 'Donald Trump, Iran' but in this case country is different which makes it bit difficult

so search shoule be given priority based on

1. 1 Category
2. Tags
3. Country

**SP i am using**

```
DECLARE @Category NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Country NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Tags NVARCHAR(4000);


    SELECT 
    ,@Category = 'Politics'
    ,@Country = 'US'
    ,@Tags = 'Donald Trump, Iran'
    FROM TestTable WHERE AutoID=1

    DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
    (
        TempNewsId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        ID INT,
        Title NVARCHAR(MAX),
        Desc NVARCHAR(MAX),
        Tags NVARCHAR(100),
        Country NVARCHAR(50),
        Category NVARCHAR(100)
    )

    IF @Category IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @Category ='%'+ @Category+'%'
            INSERT INTO @tempTable
            SELECT TOP 4
            AutoID, Title, Desc,Tags,Country,Category FROM TestTable 
            WHERE Category IS NOT NULL AND Category LIKE @Category
        END 

    IF @Tags IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @Tags ='%'+ @Tags+'%'
            INSERT INTO @tempTable
            SELECT TOP 4
            AutoID, Title, Desc,Tags,Country,Category FROM TestTable 
            WHERE Tags IS NOT NULL AND Category LIKE @Tags
        END 




    IF @Country IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @Country ='%'+ @Country+'%'
            INSERT INTO @tempTable
            SELECT TOP 4
            AutoID, Title, Desc,Tags,Country,Category FROM TestTable 
            WHERE Country IS NOT NULL AND Country LIKE @Country
        END 

    SELECT TOP 20 ID, Title,[Desc],Tags,Country,Category    FROM @tempTable 
    ORDER BY TempNewsId ASC
```

Comment: can you give an sample input example with the expected output.

Comment: Look into using full text search.  By the way, you never showed us your current query, or why you have a problem with it.

Comment: @PawanKumar, I have updated Question with one possible scenario

Comment: what is the approximate size of the table?

Comment: @gomory-chvatal, Around 330 rows and it grows at a slow page about 2-4 news per month maximum

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i have updated the question with SP i am using. `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3bd2e/13`

Answer (score 2):

The performance will not be very good, but you could create a scalar function that would compare the list of tags and return the count of similar tags.

```
create FUNCTION dbo.CompareTags
(
    @inputTagList1 varchar(255),
    @inputTagList2 varchar(255),
    @SplitOn varchar(5) = ','
)
RETURNS int
BEGIN

    declare @tagList1 table (Tag varchar(100));
    declare @tagList2 table (Tag varchar(100));

    -- populate table with first list of tags
    DECLARE @split_on_len INT = LEN(@SplitOn)
    DECLARE @start_at INT = 1
    DECLARE @end_at INT
    DECLARE @data_len INT
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        SET @end_at = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@inputTagList1,@start_at)
        SET @data_len = CASE @end_at WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@inputTagList1) ELSE @end_at-@start_at END
        INSERT INTO @tagList1 (Tag) VALUES( lower(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@inputTagList1,@start_at,@data_len)))) );
        IF @end_at = 0 BREAK;
        SET @start_at = @end_at + @split_on_len
    END

    -- populate table with second list of tags
    set @start_at = 1
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        SET @end_at = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@inputTagList2,@start_at)
        SET @data_len = CASE @end_at WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@inputTagList2) ELSE @end_at-@start_at END
        INSERT INTO @tagList2 (Tag) VALUES( lower(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@inputTagList2,@start_at,@data_len)))) );
        IF @end_at = 0 BREAK;
        SET @start_at = @end_at + @split_on_len
    END


    -- compare tables
    RETURN (select count(*) from @tagList1 as a inner join @tagList2 as b on a.Tag = b.Tag)
END
go
```

Comment: I am not sure if performance will be issue we will are dealing with about 300-400 rows

Comment: the function takes the first tag list and converts into a table with tags, it then takes the second tag list and converts into a different table with tags, it then returns the number of rows that are a match. So, `select dbo.CompareTags('a, b', 'a, b, c', ',')` will return 2 because two tags match. You can use this function when joining the original table.